# Modal images with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, image-gallery

I'm trying to create a mock image gallery using modal images.

Javascript is always a little difficult for me. I've tried to do this using the w3schools tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp), but I have tried to apply it to more than one image, which I believe to be the problem.

Is there a way to target multiple IDs? I've tried changing `document.getElementById("_");` to `document.getElementsByClassName("_");` but, still no luck. I am aware w3schools has an example of a modal gallery, but I do not want to have navigation apart of the modal content. I simply don't want the image to open up in a new tab.

I've uploaded my progress [here](https://jsfiddle.net/drsolow/drujz3wz/3/)

If anyone can help or shine a light in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var img = document.getElementsByClassName("tokyo");
var modalImg = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content");
img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
    span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName("tokyo");
```

retuens an array of elements. so you should access them with index.

```
img[0].onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
}
```